# Relationship with three tables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need help to get data from my database. I have the following models:

```
-User
--Id
--Name

-Book
--Id
--Name

-List
--Id
--Title

-BookList
--id
--List
--Book
--User
```

I am using eloquent and I would like do get data following the structure below:

```
-User
--List 1
--- Book 1
--- Book 2
--List 2
--- Book 1
--- Book 3
```

In other words, a user with multiple lists of books. In the User.php model I made the following relationship:

```
public function lists ()
{
  return $ this-> belongsToMany (
    List :: class, // related
    'books_lists', // table
    'user', // foreign pivot key
    'list' // related pivot key
  );
}

public function books ()
{
   return $ this-> belongsToMany (
      Book :: class, // related
      'books_lists', // table
      'user', // foreign pivot key
      'book' // related pivot key
   );
}
```

This way I get the following return:

```
-User
--List 1
--List 2
--Book 1
--Book 3
```

What kind of relationship I need to do to get data in desired structure?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best structure would be to merge the list and booklist table (since every book list can only have one title anyway)

```
-Users
--id
--name

-books
--id
--name

-book_list
--book_id
--list_id

-lists
--id
--title
--user_id
```

In the User.php

```php
public function lists ()
{
  return $this->hasMany(List::class);
  //no need to define the foreign keys if you name the tables and fields like above
}
```

in the List.php

```
public function books ()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);
  //no need to define the foreign keys if you name the tables and fields like above
}
```

now you can get the results with this

```php
$user = User::with('lists.books')->find($userId);
```

the result will be as follow

```php
-user
--List 1
---Book 1
---Book 2
--List 2
---Book 1
---Book 4
```

Comment: For my case, the same book can be add in different lists, for example, for the same user and different users. Examples: **List of my(user 1) favorite books:** Book 1 And Book 2, **List of portuguese books (user 1):** Book 1 and Book 3. **List of books for sell (user 2)**:  Book 1...

Answer (score 0):

A book can be added to multiple list, right? Your database structure can be better, but I assume your ERD is fixed by designer/leader. So just do it my instruction:

Add this relation to User Model(User.php):

```
public function lists ()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany (
    List::class, // related
    'books_lists', // table
    'user', // foreign pivot key
    'list' // related pivot key
  );
}
```

And this relation to List Model(List.php):

```
public function books ()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany (
      Book::class, // related
      'books_lists', // table
      'list', // foreign pivot key
      'book' // related pivot key
   )->withPivot(["user"]);
}
```

to return

```
$user = User::with(['lists.books'=> function($q)use($id){
$q->wherePivot('user', '=', $id);}])->first();
dd($user->toArray())
```

---

But it's better to change your structure to:

```
-User
--Id
--Name

-Book
--Id
--Name

-List
--Id
--Title

-BookList
--id
--List
--Book

-UserList
--List
--User
```

Comment: Hi, Following your instructions, how can I filter just one user? I tryed:
`public function show($id)
 {
   $user = User::where('id', $id)->with('lists.books')->first();
   dd($user->toArray());
  }`

But I'm getting the same list two times and inside list I'm getting books that is not for this user. How can fix this? Tks

Comment: can't you change the table as my suggest?

Comment: this second update also did not work, please, see the result here: https://pastebin.com/9DT7BYV0

Comment: I think the problem is your data, can you show me your data?

Comment: Hello Muhammad, inspired in your instructions, I could resolve my issue. I created a new table UserList and in User model I created a lists method (belongsToMany), in list model I created a books method (belongsToMany), then to get data I use the code below in my list controller: $data_user = User::where('id', $user_id)->with(['lists.books' => function ($query) use ($user_id){
            $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
        }])->get();
Thank you!

Comment: @Jader I'm having the same issue and haven't been able to solve the problem. Are you able to share the code for your models and migrations with me?